Run 2 WhatsApp desktop app on MacOS
On macOS, I have been utilizing two distinct WhatsApp applications, managing separate accounts through each app, and both have been functioning correctly for voice calls and messaging. For this case, I installed one of the applications from the App Store while the second one was downloaded from the official WhatsApp web page. Since the applications had different internal package names, everything worked seamlessly.
But after WhatsApp ceased supporting one of the older applications based on Electron, I have been unable to recreate the setup. It is now the case that I cannot run two WhatsApp applications that feature calling capability on macOS.
Is there any way to help me reverse this setup and be able to use WhatsApp’s calling features for two different accounts on my Mac?

Use WhatsApp Desktop and WhatsApp Web:
Install the WhatsApp Desktop app from the Mac App Store for one account.
Use WhatsApp Web for the second account.
Separate User Accounts on macOS:
Create a separate user account on your Mac and install WhatsApp Desktop on both accounts. You can switch between user accounts to access different WhatsApp accounts.

Not an ideal solution, the point of having two apps is to able to multitask and not to keep switching user accounts. Also I did mention it use to work earlier but not anymore.
